# Laravel 5.1 cant use @foreach on collection

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

This is data I have:
[image]

but with this blade template code:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$order->id}}</td> //51 line
            <td>{{$order->order->b_first_name}} {{$order->order->b_last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$order->order->r_first_name}} {{$order->order->r_last_name}}</td>
            <td>£{{$order->total}}</td>

            <td>{{$order->validity->diffForHumans()}}</td>


        </tr>
        @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

I got this error:

> ErrorException in fbe60fc17d23b35313269a941fc4d6f0 line 51: Trying to
>   get property of non-object (View:
>   /home/dgadmin/public_html/test/resources/views/admin/expired.blade.php)

What is the problem here? Why I cant use @foreach loop ?

Comment: are you on php7?

Comment: You should be able to. Is line 51 the foreach loop, or is it that `$order->order` does not exist?

Comment: 51 line is                 <td>{{$order->id}}</td>

Comment: Try `<?php dd($order); ?>` or `<?php Log::info($order); ?>` just after your foreach to see what it contains

Comment: Open up the `#attributes` in the collection and post it here

Comment: @aynber i got an Bitem from image above...

Comment: How are you building your collection?

Comment: $orders = Auth::user()->bitems()->where('type','v')->where('validity', '<', Carbon::now())->latest()->get(); , then send $orders to view

Comment: @zuif Here is attributes: https://imgur.com/a/6RYEh

Comment: @DaFois No, I use php5.6

Comment: Guys ANY IDEA? very frustrating for me ...

Comment: add an `empty` check for, each of the `$order`. render only if not empty. and then find the missing items and compare them in your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go into your /storage/framework/views folder and look at line 51 for the file called fbe60fc17d23b35313269a941fc4d6f0. I see you said that it was $order->id, but I was not sure if you checked the compiled view that is actually served or admin/expired.blade.php. The compiled view is the one throwing the error, so the line number will correspond with the compiled view, not the blade you are making. When you look on this line you will see what is missing. This error is thrown because you are trying to access a null value on the model. If you want to go the lazy route, change your loop to this:

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{isset($order->id)? $order->id: ''}}</td> //51 line
        <td>{{isset($order->order->b_first_name)? $order->order->b_first_name : '' }} {{isset($order->order->b_last_name)? $order->order->b_last_name : ''}}</td>
        <td>{{isset($order->order->r_first_name)? $order->order->r_first_name : ''}} {{isset($order->order->r_last_name)? $order->order->r_last_name : ''}}</td>
        <td>£{{isset($order->total)?$order->total : ''}}</td>

        <td>{{$order->validity->diffForHumans()}}</td>


    </tr>
    @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

This will print the loop as expected, changing any missing values (like the one that triggered this errror) to a blank string.

Comment: Can I change my way how to create collection ?

Comment: Now I make collection with  
$orders = Auth::user()->bitems()->where('type','v')->where('validity', '<', Carbon::now())->latest()->get(); but how create collection to use it on view on my way ?

Comment: The collection is fine and I do not believe there is way to modify a collection that would avoid this error, it's just the error that is called when a property is missing from the model and you attempt to retrieve it. One way to avoid this in the future is to set default values for your models or ensure that the data being put in is required to be there. IE: Laravel's form validation.